# Survey123 has HTML in field names

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I have published a survey via Survey123 connect. When I look at the data web page via survey123.arcgis.com, there is raw HTML code in some of the fields where the name should be. Does anyone know how to remove the code and replace it with normal text?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the field names are shown in HTML format through the data tab online? Add a few screengrabs.

Comment: Just added a screengrab

Comment: The field name "other" and "address" seems correct??

Comment: Yeah that is what makes it so weird. The field names in the xlsx file used to create this don't have any html in the names themselves or the aliases. So I am not sure why some have html and some do not

Comment: Is the xlsx formatted in any way, cell colour / font colour etc?

Comment: Can you test if this is specific to this form, or you can replicate the behavior using other forms? Also, try opening the survey in incognito/private mode.

Comment: Just the the title and a few questions, but not the ones in the screenshot